# Purpose of a Django template context object?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In one of our applications (running Django 1.8) we tend to render templates by passing a dictionary into the context parameter of the render() function and returning them as part of a view. For example:

```
from django.views.generic import View

class HomePageView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {'foo': 'bar', 'foo2': 'bar2'}
        return render(request, "page.html", context)
```

Now that I've started looking for it, I'm seeing examples of people using Django "context" objects rather than dictionaries.

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.template import Context

class HomePageView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = Context()
        context['foo'] = 'bar'
        context['foo2'] = 'bar2'
        return render(request, "page.html", context)
```

The documentation shows that this Context object can be interacted with in ways similar to a dictionary (pop, copy, key assignment, etc) and has a flatten() method that lets you compare it to a dictionary.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#playing-with-context.

My question is: Is there any reason why I would ever want to use a Context object rather than a dictionary? I can see how someone might find the subclass of RequestContext useful if they wanted easy access to request variables, but I think I'm missing the context object's utility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Python dictionary is a mapping between known keys and variable values. A [`Context()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#playing-with-context-objects) is similar to dictionary, but a [`Context()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#playing-with-context-objects) provides additional functionality.

So, when rendering a template, you need a context. This can be an instance of [`django.template.Context`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context), but `Django` comes also with a subclass [`django.template.RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) that acts slightly differently.

The [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut creates a [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) unless it's passed a different context instance explicitly.

[...]

`RequestContext` and `context processors` were created to solve the problem of redundancy. `Context processors` let you specify a number of variables that get set in each context automatically without having to specify the variables in each `render()` call.

[...]

- Keep in mind that any context processor in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` (in settings) will be available in every template prowered by that setteings file.
- Custom context perocessors can live anywhere in your code base. All Django care about is that your custom context processors are pointed to by the `context_processors` option in your `TEMPLATES` settings, or `context_processors` argument of `Engine` if you're using it directly. With that said, the is convention is to save them in a file called `context_processors.py` within your app or project.

**Source:** Mastering Django: Core. The complete Guide to Django 1.8LTS

More info: [official documentation: RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext)

Comment: Ahhh i had missed the line in the documentation about how templates need a context object, but passing a dictionary into the render function *instantiates* a RequestContext object as a shortcut. Great to know, thanks!